# includesしたモデルが持つレコードが存在しない場合の対処について

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

PublicActivityのgemを使ってるのですが、activitiesを取得する時にパフォーマンス改善のために出来るだけまとめてSQLで取ってくるようにしたいです。

```
PublicActivity::Activity.includes(trackable: [:post]).where(trackable_type: ['Like', 'Comment'])
```

そこで上記のようにtrackableとその先のpostまでincludesすることによってパフォーマンスは改善したのですが、`post`レコードが存在しない時(削除した時など)に、

`Association named 'post' was not found`というエラーが出ます。

`joins`を使えば、存在するレコードだけ取ってくる、と聞いて使おうとすると今度は
`Cannot eagerly load the polymorphic association`というエラーが出ます。

何か良い解決方法はありますでしょうか?

関連するモデルの情報が抜けておりました。追記致します。

Postモデル

```
Class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
```

Commentモデル

```
Class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PublicActivity::Common 
  belongs_to :post
  has_many :likes
```

Likeモデル

```
Class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PublicActivity::Common 
  belongs_to :comment
```

となっています。

Comment: モデル定義やエラーのトレースバックは載せられますか? `question` がどこに属するものかが分からないです。(質問は後から[edit]して補足を追加できます)

Comment: 詳細がよくわからないのですが、ここのページの内容が参考になるかもしれません。 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20701770/in-rails-how-to-eager-load-an-association-only-if-the-association-is-not-nil

Comment: @JunichiIto コメントではなく回答として投稿して頂ければと思います。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: @ento

失礼いたしました。
`question`ではなく、`post`でした。
また、関連するモデルの内容を追加いたしました。

Comment: @yang8 再現情報の追加ありがとうございます!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`includes` を使ったクエリを手元で試したところ、`Like` に `post` という名前のアソシエーションは無い、というエラーメッセージになりました (Postレコードは削除していない状態でです):

> ActiveRecord::AssociationNotFoundError: Association named 'post' was not found on Like; perhaps you misspelled it?

この場合、`post` アソシエーションを `Like` に追加することで通るようになります:

```
class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
    include PublicActivity::Common
    belongs_to :comment
    has_one :post, :through => :comment
end
```

コンソール上で、発行されるクエリを確認:

```
> post = Post.new
> post.save
> post.comments << Comment.new
> comment = Comment.first
> comment.likes << Like.new
> like = Like.first
> like.create_activity key: 'like.create'
> PublicActivity::Activity.includes(trackable: [:post]).where(trackable_type: ['Like', 'Comment'])
  PublicActivity::Activity Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "activities".* FROM "activities"  WHERE "activities"."trackable_type" IN ('Like', 'Comment')
  Like Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "likes".* FROM "likes"  WHERE "likes"."id" IN (1)
  Comment Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments"  WHERE "comments"."id" IN (1)
  Post Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"  WHERE "posts"."id" IN (1)
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<PublicActivity::Activity id: 2, ...>]>
```

なぜエラーになっていたか:

問題のクエリで、`Activity.trackable` に入ってくるのは `Like` または `Comment` モデルです:

```
PublicActivity::Activity.includes(trackable: [:post]).where(trackable_type: ['Like', 'Comment'])
```

`trackable: [:post]` は、 `Like` または `Comment` に定義されている `post` アソシエーションを取ってこい、と言っていることになります。エラーになっていたのは、`Like` には `post` アソシエーションが無かったためです。

Rails にあまり詳しくないので、もっとクエリを減らす方法はあるかもしれません。

Comment: 有難うございます。確認いたします！

Comment: 解決しました。有難うございます。
単純なミスでお恥ずかしいです。

Answer (score 2):

「ネットで検索したらそれっぽい情報が見つかった」というレベルですが、こちらのページが参考になるかもしれません。
一度チェックしてみてください。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20701770/in-rails-how-to-eager-load-an-association-only-if-the-association-is-not-nil

ちなみに、「activitiesを取得する時にパフォーマンス改善のために出来るだけまとめてSQLで取ってくる」というのは **eager loading** と呼ばれるテクニック（？）なので、"PublicActivity eager load"というキーワードで検索してみました。

こうすると英語のページがたくさん引っかかると思うので、見つかったページを調べていくと答えが見つかるかもしれません。

こちらもご参考までに。

Comment: 有難うございます！こちらの記事も読んだのですが、解決しませんでした。